# javaFX - How to create a resizable rectangle?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to produce a GUI desktop app and it should run on different systems well. In first Step I want to create a rectangle that appears well in different screens like 1920*1080 and 800*600 . This rectangle size in first system should be 900 * 500 and in second one its scale should be 500 * 350 (The Scales are just examples!) How can i define a rectangle that work in this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about [Responsive Design](http://www.guigarage.com/2015/09/how-to-create-a-responsive-layout-in-javafx/).Below is an example of what you want to make.Although is not best solution,with this i mean it can be modified for better performance(I also have added some code to move the window if it is `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` Drag the Window to have see this):

[image]

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class FX extends Application {

    int screenWidth = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();

    Stage stage;
    Scene scene;

    int initialX;
    int initialY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {

        // root
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:rgb(186,153,122,0.7); -fx-background-radius:30;");

        // Responsive Design
        int sceneWidth = 0;
        int sceneHeight = 0;
        if (screenWidth <= 800 && screenHeight <= 600) {
            sceneWidth = 600;
            sceneHeight = 350;
        } else if (screenWidth <= 1280 && screenHeight <= 768) {
            sceneWidth = 800;
            sceneHeight = 450;
        } else if (screenWidth <= 1920 && screenHeight <= 1080) {
            sceneWidth = 1000;
            sceneHeight = 650;
        }

        // Scene
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight, Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // Moving
        scene.setOnMousePressed(m -> {
            if (m.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                scene.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                initialX = (int) (stage.getX() - m.getScreenX());
                initialY = (int) (stage.getY() - m.getScreenY());
            }
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(m -> {
            if (m.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                stage.setX(m.getScreenX() + initialX);
                stage.setY(m.getScreenY() + initialY);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnMouseReleased(m -> {
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Main Method
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Are you [happy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=819dBOcHVTU)?:)

Comment: My question is then what layouts like grid pane can do ? Can i use them here for my problem?

Comment: The above is an example.You can save screen resolution in variables ScreenWidth and ScreenHeight what you mean?What exactly you want to make?You want the window to be transparent?Only a rectangle without default window minimize maximize close to be shown?

Comment: I will add an example as soon as i get to computer.

Comment: look , assume that i am coding in my pc and its resolution is 1920*1080 as i told. Well , I want to have a green rectangle in center of my app in size of 1000 * 500 . This size is good enough for my screen. Assume that my brother have a pc too but its monitor'resolution is 800*600 and i want that rectangle that i have created in my pc to be centered and nice in my brother pc. But with that size that rectangle doesn't shown completely ( 1000 is bigger than 800) . So it should be resized !

Comment: @Aref Hoseinikia rewritten the answer!

Comment: Ok ! I think i understand . I should define the size of the rectangle according to screen size . tnx ! But assume that i have more components and shapes . So what can we do in that case ? Should we define sizes for each one for 3 types of resolution ???

Comment: Yoy have to work with layouts.They are very helpfull.But except that you have to think what components should me visible in 800*600 resolution in 1200*800.You have to imagine it and then write the code.When you see a website if you make the window smaller its navigation bar will change.Some components will not be shown.You have to imagine how it will be.Companies have people that are working only for that,the user interface.It is not so easy.So start learning all the layouts,think how you want it to be in different resolutions and write the code.See videos about layouts on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

The `Rectange` class in JavaFX package itself is a resizable rectangle already since you can change the width/height and the location as well. You just need to figure out the current resolution and change the size of it.

See [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html)

Comment: Well , What should i do in the first step? I mean in creating and defining the rectangle . What is its size ?

Comment: @ArefHoseinikia You can get the screen size from `Screen` class. And just scale your rectangle accordingly.